# Hide or stop seeing my own posts on my Tumblr dashboard

Tags: tumblr

On my Tumblr Dashboard I not only see the posts from people I follow, but also mine. I don't want to see my posts there (particularly since they're reblogs only).

How do I stop or exclude them from showing up? Or is there a view I could use to browse content from people I follow without seeing my reblogs?

I was previously using soup.io (a German made Tumblr alternative). There I would switch to the "Friends" tab to view posts from people I follow and repost what I liked. Is there a similar function or setting in Tumblr?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Tumblr offers no way of customising one's Dashboard, including a way to hide one's own posts.

There is, however, a third-party browser extension called [Tumblr Savior](http://bjornstar.com/tumblr-savior) for Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera that allows one to hide posts containing certain, user-specified words or phrases from one's Dashboard, along with offering a few other. This would work perfectly for your purpose: just add your blog URL(s) to Tumblr Savior's blacklist.

The main drawback of this is that it is browser-specific, so you would need Tumblr Savior to be set up on any browser on which you would log into Tumblr and browse your Dashboard. The extension is also not compatible with mobile browsers nor the official Tumblr app. However, at the present time, this is probably as close as one can get to hiding one's own posts from the Dashboard.